# sharing laptop's internet to iphone

Tags: windows-vista

I am using a laptop with vista, earlier i was able to share its wired internet to my iPhone by checking the checkbox share the internet connection, but now my company has introduced some kind of policy, where in once i check the checkbox and click ok the local area network connection gets disconnected.

I know there is some sort of service that is running to block this sharing. Is there any way to figure it out and enable the sharing again...

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop supports WIFI then you can do it by [setting up your ad hoc connection](http://www.home-network-help.com/ad-hoc-wireless.html)

Comment: I am following the same step but as soon as i check he checkbox share network then my local area connection goes away...